# Replace uinavigationbar by uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to replace uinavigationbar by uisearchbar in a specific view can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Hide the navigationbar in that view as follows....

```
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

And add the UISearchBar. You can hide the navigationbar in viewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear.